# Unable to start MySQL Cluster

Tags: mysql

I am trying to set-up MySQL Cluster 7.4.7 on 2 Ubuntu 14.04 machines with below configuration:

**Machine 1**

Management node 1

Sql node 2

Data node 2

API node 2

**Machine 2**

Sql node 1

Data node 1

API node 1

On clicking Deploy and start cluster in the wizard, I get this error:

```
Command ‘[u’/path/to/cluster/bin/ndb_mgmd’, ‘--initial’, ‘—ndb-nodeid=49’, ‘--config-dir=/path/MySQL_Cluster/49/’, ‘—config-file=/path/MySQL_Cluster/49/config.ini’]’ retuned non-zero exit status 1
```

As I understood, it is giving error while starting management node but not able to figure out what's wrong with it.

Please suggest what am I missing? Also, how can I get verbose description of the error, may be somewhere in logs, to troubleshoot it.